# MongoDb: Space in key name?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I've got a bit of an issue that has caused me to bash my head against the wall for a couple of days.

Consider the following document:

```
{
    '_id': '5d7de43ac7baaa0ff2c4ae2bd000518a',
    'Some Complex Name': {
        'data': {
            'simpleKey': [
                {
                    'name': 'Bob',
                    'age': 30
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Sam',
                    'age': 31
                },
                {
                    'name': 'George',
                    'age': 20
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In my understanding of JavaScript, I have learned that I would refer to the 'Some Complex Name' in the following manner (from within the scope of a `map` function):

```
var stuff = this['Some Complex Name']
```

Building from that, I would be able to access the names with the following:

```
var names = [];
for (var i in this['Some Complex Name'].data.simpleKey) {
    names.push(this['Some Complex Name'].data.simpleKey[i].name);
}
emit(this._id, names);
```

Unfortunately, I'm wrong somewhere on this, as I'm getting an error like this

```
        "errmsg" : "exception: map invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: this['Some Complex Name'] has no properties nofile_b:2"
```

Thus, my question: How would I /properly/ access the 'Some Complex Name' key?

A bonus would be some documentation to explain this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just found the answer and it's exactly what I suspected.

[MongoDB/PyMongo: How to use dot notation in a Map function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619176/mongodb-pymongo-how-to-use-dot-notation-in-a-map-function) was the same issue, and as it turns out I needed to filter my query to make sure `Some Complex Name` existed in the documents I was working with. This was accomplished via the `query` to `mapReduce`.